# Bathroom tub drain

Tags: bathtub

I have a bath tub drain which is very different, and I need to find a stopper for it. My drain has a piece in the middle of it, so a normal stopper won’t work.

Comment: A picture is probably necessary.

Answer (score 2):

If all else fails, something like this will probably work.

[image]

It covers the whole drain and just sticks from the top.  Water pressure holds it down.